# Building JS quiz, alert window repeats previous Q instead of asking next Q

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a mini quiz in JavaScript. Currently, the quiz issues an alert when you answer a question correctly. In addition to notifying the user that they are correct, I would like the same alert window to also ask the user the next question i.e. "You answered this question correctly! Now here is the next question..."

However, instead of asking the next question, it repeats the previous one, which was just answered correctly. Here is my code:

```
var questions = [
{
question: "What is the capital of England?",
answer: "LONDON",
},

{
question: "What is the capital of France?",
answer: "PARIS",
},

{
question: "What is the capital of Germany?",
answer: "BERLIN",
}
];

var correctAnswers = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
question = questions[i].question;
answer = questions[i].answer;
response = prompt(question);
if (response.toUpperCase() === answer){
alert("Correct! " + questions[i].question);
correctAnswers ++;
}
else {
alert("Incorrect. The answer was " + questions[i].answer);
}
}

html = correctAnswers + " correct answers."
document.write(html);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`alert` should be asking next question. So do `i+1`

```
alert("Correct! " + questions[i+1].question);
```

```js
var questions = [{
    question: "What is the capital of England?",
    answer: "LONDON",
  },

  {
    question: "What is the capital of France?",
    answer: "PARIS",
  },

  {
    question: "What is the capital of Germany?",
    answer: "BERLIN",
  }
];

var correctAnswers = 0;
var response="";
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  question = questions[i].question;
  answer = questions[i].answer;
  response = response!=""?prompt("Correct! "+question):prompt(question);
  if (response.toUpperCase() === answer) {
    correctAnswers++;
    if(i==questions.length-1)
      alert("Correct");
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect. The answer was " + questions[i].answer);
  }
}
html = correctAnswers + " correct answers."
document.body.innerHTML=html;
```

Comment: Thank you! That code helped, but when alert asked the next question, there was no space for the user to enter their answer. They have to click "Ok" and then another alert window appears where the question repeats, this time with a space to answer. Any idea how I could fix this?